# Ionic content of different samples of water

Tags: water

So I was reading about impurities of in water and I have a question in mind:

So say we have distilled water, deionized water, tap water and soft water which was softened using dowex resin or any other cation exchange resin.

So my question is which samples would contain anions like $\ce{Cl^-}$ and $\ce{PO4^-}$ and which would contain cations like $\ce{Ca^2+}$ and $\ce{Mg^2+}$?

My speculation is that tap water would contain all the stated ions, deionized water wouldn't contain any, distilled water wouldn't contain any, and softened water would contain the anions but not the cations since $\ce{Ca^2+}$ and $\ce{Mg^2+}$ would be replaced by $\ce{Na^+}$ or so.

Thank you!